# ¿Como obtener el valor del input con JavaScript cuando cambia su valor (keyup) en modal editar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

Laravel 8
PHP 7.4
mySQL

Tengo un dilema con un formulario de Editar

Estoy tratando de validar que el código de un producto no se repita, yo uso tres campos para realizar la validación: **equipo, marca y modelo**, y al guardar en base de datos los concateno para formar el **Código** del producto, por lo tanto para validar en tiempo real ocupo enviar los tres valores por **Ajax**. Cree un evento para obtener el **id del producto** de acuerdo al modal seleccionado, para ello en el botón que abre mi modal le agregue **data-producto_id="{{$p->id}}"**, luego lo guarde en una variable de Javascript:

```js
$('.producto_del').click(function(evento) {

  var producto_idEditar = $(evento.target).data('producto_id');

});
```

Después ocupaba traer el valor del input **"equipo"** para que en caso de que lo editaran obtener el valor, pero también ocupaba traer el valor actual en caso de que no lo editaran, agregue a mi botón que abre el modal dos **data** para traer el valor de la marca y el modelo,mi función quedo así:

```js
/** COMIENZA VALIDACIÓN CÓDIGO **/

$('.producto_del').click(function(event) {

  var producto_idEditar = $(event.target).data('producto_id');
  var modeloData = $(event.target).data('modelo');
  var marcaData = $(event.target).data('marca');

  $(document).on('keyup', '#codigoEditar', function(evento) {

    const target = $(evento.currentTarget);
    var editarCodigo = target.val();
    var longitudCodigoEditar = target.val().length;

    // console.log(editarCodigo);

    if (longitudCodigoEditar > 0) {

      var codC = editarCodigo;
      var mC = marcaData;
      // console.log(mC);
      var modC = modeloData;
      var idP = producto_idEditar;

      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });


      var url = '{{ url('
      validarCodigoEditar ') }}';

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          codC,
          mC,
          modC,
          idP
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(response) {

          if (response.success == 1) {


            console.log("pertenece a otro registro");

          } else if (response.success == 0) {

            console.log("propio");

          } else if (response.success == 2) {

            console.log("disponible");

          }

        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        }

      });


    } else {

      console.log('Entre a verificar 0 y vacio ajax');

    }

  });
});

/** TERMINA VALIDACIÓN CÓDIGO **/
```

Y en mi controlador:

```js
public
function ajaxRequestPostCodigoEditar(Request $request) {

  $jsonData = array();

  $codigo = $request - > a.
  " ".$request - > b.
  " ".$request - > c;
  $idProd = $request - > d;

  $buscarCodigo = catProd::select('codigoE') -
    > where([
      ['codigoE', '=', $codigo], // no coincide entonces no pertenece al propio registro
      ['id', '=', $idProd]
    ]) - > get();

  $buscarCodigo2 = catProd::select('codigoE') -
    > where('codigoE', '=', $codigo) // coincide o no
    -
    > get();

  $existeCodigo = count($buscarCodigo);
  $existeCodigo2 = count($buscarCodigo2);

  if ($existeCodigo > 0 && $existeCodigo2 > 0) {

    $jsonData['success'] = 0;

    $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: green;">Código ('.$codigo.
    ') disponible</strong></p>';

  } else if ($existeCodigo <= 0 && $existeCodigo2 > 0) {

    $jsonData['success'] = 1;

    $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: red;">El código <strong style="color: black;">('.$codigo.
    ')</strong> pertenece a otro registro</strong></p>';

  } else if ($existeCodigo <= 0 && $existeCodigo2 <= 0) {

    $jsonData['success'] = 2;

    $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: green;">Código disponible</strong></p>';

  }


  return response() - > json(
    [
      'success' => $jsonData['success'],
      'message' => $jsonData['message']
    ]
  );


}
```

Hasta aquí me funciona para traer los datos del modal seleccionado pero no me lee los datos después del evento keyup, aquí dejo una muestra:

> Datos cuando se abre el modal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Datos después de un evento keyup en cualquiera de los campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en la imagen anterior el valor del input es **ACERO** pero no se puede leer solo se lee el valor de los datos cargados al abrir el modal.

este es mi index.blade.php

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row align-items-center my-4">
        <div class="col">
          <h2 class="h3 mb-0 page-title">Lista de Equipos</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="activarFuncion();" style="color:white">
            <span style="color:white"></span> {{ __('Agregar equipo') }}
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
      <div class="alert alert-primary">
        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
      </div>
      @endif

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table datatables table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTable-1">
          <form action="">
            @csrf
            <div class="row flex">
              <div class="field py-2 col-md-5">
                <input type="search" id="q" name="search" class="form-control col-md-12" style="font-size: 16px;" placeholder="Buscar...">
              </div>
              <div class="field py-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px;">Buscar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <tr>
            <th hidden="">#</th>
            <th>{{ __('Codigo') }}</th>
            <th>{{ __('Descripcion') }}</th>
            <!-- <th>{{ __('Tipo') }}</th> -->
            @can('admin.producto.update')
            <th colspan="3">{{ __('Acciones') }}</th>
            @endcan
          </tr>
          @if($productos->count())
          <tbody>
            @if($search)
            <h6>
              <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                Los resultados para tu busqueda '{{ $search }}' son:
              </div>
            </h6>
            @endif @foreach($productos as $posicion => $p) @if($p->estatusProd == 'Activo')
            <tr>
              <td hidden="">{{ $p->id }}</td>
              <td><a href="{{ route('admin.producto.show', $p) }}">{{ $p->codigoE }}</a></td>
              <td>{{ $p->descripcionProd }}</td>
              <!--<td>{{ $p->tipo_id }}</td>-->
              @can('admin.producto.update')
              <td width="10px">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary producto_del" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalE{{ $p->id }}" data-producto_id="{{$p->id}}" data-marca="{{$p->marca}}" data-modelo="{{$p->modelo}}">
  Editar
</button>

              </td>
              @endcan
            </tr>

            @include('admin.producto.modals.edit') @endif @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 1%;">
          <strong>   {{ $productos->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-4') }}</strong>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
    <!-- .col-12 -->
  </div>
  <!-- .row -->
</div>
<!-- .container-fluid -->
@else
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>No se encontraron resultados para tu busqueda '{{ $search }}'</strong>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

@endif
```

Y este mi modal edit.blade.php:

```html
<form action="{{ route('admin.producto.update', $p->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf @method('PUT')
  <div class="modal fade text-left modalEditarProd" id="myModalE{{ $p->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{ __('Editar información de equipo') }}</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          @if($p->clasificacion_id == '1')
          <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
            <strong for="" style="color: black; font-size: 14px">{{ __('Código') }}</strong>
          </div>

          <div hidden>
            <input type="text" value="{{ $p->id }}" name="idProd" id="idProd">
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">

            <div class="col">
              <strong for="">{{ __('Categoria:') }}</strong>
              <select name="categoriaEditar" id="categoriaEditar" class="form-control col-md-12 categoriaEdit" required>
                <option value="{{ $p->categoria }}">{{ $p->categoria }}</option>
                <option value="Bifasico">Bifasico</option>
                <option value="Monofasico">Monofasico</option>
                <option value="Trifasico">Trifasico</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
            <div class="col" id="grupo__codigoEditar">
              <strong>Equipo</strong>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input codigoEdit" type="text" name="codigoEditar" id="codigoEditar" value="{{ $p->codigo }}">
              <p id="respuestaCodigoEditar"></p>
              <div class="errorVacioEditar" id="errorVacioEditar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col" id="grupo__marcaEditar">
              <strong>{{ __('Marca') }}</strong>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input marcaEdit" type="text" name="marcaEditar" id="marcaEditar" value="{{ $p->marca }}">
              <p id="respuestaMarcaEditar"></p>
              <div class="errorVacioMarcaEditar" id="errorVacioMarcaEditar"></div>


            </div>
            <div class="col" id="grupo__modeloEditar">
              <strong>{{ __('Modelo') }}</strong>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input modeloEdit" type="text" name="modeloEditar" id="modeloEditar" value="{{ $p->modelo }}">
              <p id="respuestaModeloEditar"></p>
              <div class="errorVacioEditarModelo" id="errorVacioEditarModelo"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row" style="margin-top: 2%;">

            <div class="form-group col">

              <strong>{{ __('Capacidad en VA') }}</strong>
              <input class="form-control capWattsEdit" type="text" name="capWattsEditar" id="capWattsEditar" value="{{ $p->capWatts }}">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">

              <strong>{{ __('Potencia en watts') }}:</strong>
              <input class="form-control potWattsEdit" type="text" name="potWattsEditar" id="potWattsEditar" value="{{ $p->potWatts }}">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong>{{ __('Capacidad en bateria') }}:</strong>
              <input class="form-control canBateriasEdit" type="text" name="canBateriasEditar" id="canBateriasEditar" value="{{ $p->canBaterias }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong>{{ __('Voltaje de bateria') }}:</strong>
              <input class="form-control volBateriasEdit" type="text" name="volBateriasEditar" id="volBateriasEditar" value="{{ $p->volBaterias }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong>{{ __('Amperaje bateria') }}:</strong>
              <input class="form-control ampBatEdit" type="text" name="ampBatEditar" id="ampBatEditar" value="{{ $p->ampBat }}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong>{{ __('Carga en watts') }}</strong>
              <input type="text" class="form-control cargaEdit" value="{{ $p->carga }}" name="cargaEditar" id="cargaEditar">
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 42%;">
            <strong for="" style="color: black; font-size: 14px">{{ __('Tiempo esperado de batería') }}</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row" style="margin-top: 1%;">

            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong>{{ __('Tipo') }}:</strong>
              <select class="form-control tipo_idEdit" name="tipo_idEditar" id="tipo_idEditar">
                <option value="{{ $p->idTipo }}">{{ $p->nameTipo }}</option>
                @foreach ($tipo as $t)
                <option value="{{ $t->id }}">{{ $t->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong for="">{{ __('Horas') }}</strong>
              <input type="text" class="form-control horasEdit" value="{{ $p->horas }}" name="horasEditar" id="horasEditar" maxlength="2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong for="">{{ __('Minutos') }}</strong>
              <input type="text" class="form-control minutosEdit" value="{{ $p->minutos }}" name="minutosEditar" id="minutosEditar" maxlength="2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong for="">{{ __('Segundos') }}</strong>
              <input type="text" class="form-control segundosEdit" value="{{ $p->segundos }}" name="segundosEditar" id="segundosEditar" maxlength="2">
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-row">

            <div class="form-group col-2" id="ocultarClasi">
              <strong>{{ __('Clasificación:') }}</strong>
              <select class="form-control clasificacionEdit" name="clasificacionEditar" id="clasificacionEditar">
                <option value="{{ $p->clasificacion_id }}">{{ $p->clasificacion }}</option>
                @foreach ($clasificacion as $clasif) @if($clasif->clasificacion == 'UPS' || $clasif->clasificacion == 'Otros')
                <option value="{{ $clasif->id }}">{{ $clasif->clasificacion }}</option>
                @endif @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">

              <strong>{{ __('Descripción') }}:</strong>
              <textarea class="form-control descripcionEdit" name="descripcionEditar" cols="2" rows="4" id="descripcionEditar">{{ strtoupper($p->descripcionProd) }}
                        </textarea>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group col">
              <strong>{{ __('Comentarios') }}:</strong>
              <textarea class="form-control ComentariosEdit" type="text" cols="2" rows="4" name="ComentariosEditar" id="ComentariosEditar">{{ $p->Comentarios }}</textarea>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="BackEdit()">
            <span style="color:white"></span> {{ __('Regresar') }}
          </a>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAgregar">{{ __('Guardar') }}</button>
        </div>

        @elseif($p->clasificacion_id == 2)

        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
          <strong for="" style="color: black; font-size: 14px">{{ __('Código') }}</strong>
        </div>

        <div hidden>
          <input type="text" value="{{ $p->id }}" name="idProd" id="idProd">
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">


          <div class="col" id="grupo__codigoEditar">
            <strong>Equipo</strong>
            <input class="form-control formulario__input codigoEdit" type="text" name="codigoEditar" id="codigoEditar" value="{{ $p->codigo }}">
            <p id="respuestaCodigoEditar"></p>
            <div class="errorVacioEditar" id="errorVacioEditar"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col" id="grupo__marcaEditar">
            <strong>{{ __('Marca') }}</strong>
            <input class="form-control formulario__input marcaEdit" type="text" name="marcaEditar" id="marcaEditar" value="{{ $p->marca }}">
            <p id="respuestaMarcaEditar"></p>
            <div class="errorVacioMarcaEditar" id="errorVacioMarcaEditar"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col" id="grupo__modeloEditar">
            <strong>{{ __('Modelo') }}</strong>
            <input class="form-control formulario__input modeloEdit" type="text" name="modeloEditar" id="modeloEditar" value="{{ $p->modelo }}">
            <p id="respuestaModeloEditar"></p>
            <div class="errorVacioEditarModelo" id="errorVacioEditarModelo"></div>
          </div>
        </div>




        <div class="form-row" style="margin-top: 1%;">

          <div class="form-group col-2">
            <strong>{{ __('Tipo') }}:</strong>
            <select class="form-control tipo_idEdit" name="tipo_idEditar" id="tipo_idEditar">
              <option value="{{ $p->idTipo }}">{{ $p->nameTipo }}</option>
              @foreach ($tipo as $t)
              <option value="{{ $t->id }}">{{ $t->name }}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-2" id="ocultarClasi">
            <strong>{{ __('Clasificación:') }}</strong>
            <select class="form-control clasificacionEdit" name="clasificacionEditar" id="clasificacionEditar">
              <option value="{{ $p->clasificacion_id }}">{{ $p->clasificacion }}</option>
              @foreach ($clasificacion as $clasif) @if($clasif->clasificacion == 'UPS' || $clasif->clasificacion == 'Otros')
              <option value="{{ $clasif->id }}">{{ $clasif->clasificacion }}</option>
              @endif @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col">

            <strong>{{ __('Descripción') }}:</strong>
            <textarea class="form-control descripcionEdit" cols="2" rows="4" name="descripcionEditar" id="descripcionEditar">{{ strtoupper($p->descripcionProd) }}</textarea>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group col">
            <strong>{{ __('Comentarios') }}:</strong>
            <textarea class="form-control ComentariosEdit" type="text" cols="2" rows="4" name="ComentariosEditar" id="ComentariosEditar">{{ $p->Comentarios }}</textarea>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="BackEdit()">
          <span style="color:white"></span> {{ __('Regresar') }}
        </a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAgregar">{{ __('Guardar') }}</button>
      </div>

      @endif

    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cualquier declaración de una variable con el ID del producto que hagas dentro de un handlers o dentro de una función en general sólo existe en ese contexto. Cuando envías el formulario

```
d = producto_idEditar
```

Está vacío (y si tienes abierta la consola debiera reclamar).

Dónde sea que se abra el modal dices que le añades un data attribute, así que al validar el envío del formulario debieras leer ese data attribute para saber qué producto se va a enviar.

Respecto a la marca y modelo o los demás datos en general, los estás obteniendo usando el ID. Según yo, si tienes varias filas de productos y cada uno abre un modal de edición, entonces tienes id repetidos.

Pareciera más sano usar el nombre de esos inputs (y si no tienen fíjales uno, no importa que se repitan en cada fila) o una clase, pero para obtener su valor acota la selección a la fila que se va a modificar, no a todo el documento como haces ahora.

El error en el backend y en el hadler que manda el Ajax es imposible diagnosticarlo hasta estar seguros de que se están enviando los valores (puedes mirar el payload en la pestaña network de Chrome devtools)

Si editas tu pregunta poniendo el html de la tabla o grilla de productos editaré la respuesta con una sugerencia más específica.